# Adding variable to string in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

Ok, so it's easy in VB, but I can't figure it out in C#:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblUsers WHERE username = '" & username & "'", cn);
```

This throws

```
 CS0019: Operator '&' cannot be applied to operands of type 'string' and 'string'
```

Googled it and can't find an answer, help this newbie here please!

Comment: Use + operator instead of & operator.

Comment: SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblUsers WHERE username = '" + username + " OR 1=1'", cn);

Comment: Paco, what does that achieve?

Comment: All the users will be removed from the database.

Comment: @Tom, that's how a hacker would enter a garbage value for "username" to make your query always true.

Comment: I always sanitise all input before running it through queries

Comment: @Tom, sad experience says that it's not possible to write a "sanitizing" filter that's as smart as the accumulated knowledge of hackers. Parameters are the only safe way to prevent SQL injection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've already got six (and counting) recommendations to use + instead of &. However, you'd be much better off in the long run to use a parameterized query instead of concatenating a variable directly into the SQL statement. By concatenating, especially if that's user input, you are wide open for SQL injection attacks. By using parameters, you block SQL injection.

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblUsers WHERE username = @user");
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@user",  username);
```

Comment: Excellent point, +1. I'd not really looked at the overall problem there and yes, you should usually be using sql parameters for this sort of thing.

Comment: It should be said that I always sanitise my input before running it in a query, I am aware of the pitfalls of SQL injections, but this seems like another good defence.

Answer (score 3):

Use `+` to concatentate strings. `&` functions as either a unary or a binary operator.

**However, the correct answer is to use parameterized queries!**

The method you are using is subject to [SQL injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection) attacks.

Answer (score 2):

use the '+' instead of the '&'

Answer (score 2):

`+` is the string concatenation operator in C#.

Answer (score 2):

Use a "+" instead of "&"

SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblUsers WHERE username = '" + username + "'", cn);

Answer (score 2):

Use + instead

i.e.

```
'" + username + "'"
```

Answer (score 2):

The other option which I prefer for this sort of thign is String.Format:

```
SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(String.Format("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblUsers WHERE username = '{0}'",username ), cn);
```